# Awk regex for matching a set of values

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I having an Issue with awk regex matching. I was trying to match a particular column with a regex pattern `(\"\.\"|0|1)`. This column can have only values `"."`,`0` or `1`. But my regex pattern is not matching in awk while the data in column is `"."`. any thoughts??

code

```
awk -F "$delimitter" -v n="$column" -v m="$pattern" 'NR!=1 && $n !~ "^" m "$" {
                         printf "%s:%s:%s\n", FILENAME, FNR, $n  > "/dev/stderr"
                         count++
                       }
                       END {print count+0}' input.txt 2>> errors.log
```

Comment: While you seem to have gotten the answer you needed, could you for the benefit of future readers edit your post to include example input, desired output and the unwanted current output of your `awk` program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the pattern to match exactly on either `"."` (with quotes included), `0` or `1`, you'd need the pattern to be `^("\."|[01])$` or `^("[.]"|[01])$` or `^("\."|0|1)$`, etc.

But when using `-v` to pass that pattern to `awk`, you have the problem that `awk` treats `\` specially there (same happens for `-F x` which is similar to `-v FS=x`), so you'd need to escape the backslashes here.

It's better to use `ENVIRON` to pass arbitrary strings from shell to `awk` as that doesn't have that issue.

So:

```
pattern='"\."|0|1'
PATTERN=$pattern DELIMITER=$delimiter awk -v n="$n" '
  BEGIN {FS = ENVIRON["DELIMITER"]; m = ENVIRON["PATTERN"]}
  $n ~ "^(" m ")$" {...}'
```

(still using `-v` for `n` as those are expected to be numbers so without backslash).

Note the `(`, `)` above. `^x|y$` would be either `x` at the start or `y` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the word "pattern" when matching text as it's highly ambiguous. Use "string" or "regexp", whichever one you mean. See [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) for more information.

It sound like you're going about this wrong and using a regexp comparison where a string comparison in a hash lookup would be clearer, less fragile and more efficient.

```
valid='"."|0|1'
awk -F "$delimitter" -v n="$column" -v m="$valid" '
    BEGIN {
        split(m,tmp,"|")
        for (i in tmp) {
            valid[tmp[i]]
        }
    }
    NR>1 && !($n in valid) {
        printf "%s:%s:%s\n", FILENAME, FNR, $n  > "/dev/stderr"
        count++
    }
    END {print count+0}
' input.txt
```

If any of the shell variables can contain escape sequences (those in your example do not) then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script for other ways than `-v` to pass their values to awk, e.g. `ENVIRON[]` or `ARGV[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `[.01]` as your pattern.

That's a bracket expression which matches only `.`, `0`, and `1`.

NOTE: outside of a bracket expression, you'd have to escape a `.` as `\.` (otherwise it will match ANY character), but inside a bracket expression it will be treated as a literal `.`

Comment: OP seems wants `"."`,`0` or `1` to match